# css border is not show although I make it

Tags: html, css

This is my html code

```
<div id="vertical-chart-total-calls-statuses" class="chart-holder" style="border:10px #000">
                        <canvas class="overlay" width="478" height="265"></canvas>
                    </div>
```

I draw the canvas using a library.

My problem is that the div `vertical-chart-total-calls-statuses` doesn't have a border. why please?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `solid`

```
border:10px solid #000
```

Border-style reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style)

Answer (score 4):

You have not specified the border-style.

You can use any of the style and it will appear.

Eg :

```
  border: 10px #000 solid;
  border: 10px #000 dashed;
  border: 10px #000 groove;
  border: 10px #000 inset;
  border: 10px #000 outset;
```

Etc....

Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr%5fborder-style.asp) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a type for the border, eg `solid`, `dotted`, `dashed`.

Change your style attribute to `border:10px solid #000;` and it will work.